# Hashing a generator expression

Tags: python, hash, generator

Apparently python will allow me to hash a generator expression like `(i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

```
>>> hash(i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
8735741846615
```

On closer inspection however, this hash value is always the same no matter what generator I put into it!

```
>>> hash(i for i in range(2))
8735741846615
>>> hash(i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
8735741846615
>>> hash(i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
8735741846615
```

why is this happening? Why is hashing a generator even allowed?

I need to do this because I’m storing stuff in a dictionary cache. You access entries in the cache by passing lists of objects. But certain groups of lists with different items should still point to the same entry, since the only thing that matters here is the integer value of one attribute in each list item. So they should hash only based on those integer values, not anything relating to the items themselves, to avoid unnecessary cache misses.

I'm aware you can always just convert the expression to a tuple, but I was asking if you can bypass that by simply using the output of the generator without the tuple container, similar to how `sum()` could be used for such a thing.

Comment: I am using `Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330] on linux`

Comment: It seems that hash on generators is related to the memory address of the object. If I repeat your code I get the same result. However if I define different variable for each generator (so that these objects are not automatically deleted after each line) then hashes are different. So generally these don't have the same hash.

Comment: Quoting [docs about hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) _All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are_. I guess technically (for common cases) generators are not mutable. Not sure how that works with `generator.send` though (but I'm curious for the answer).

Comment: then why is hashing of generators allowed then?

Comment: Don't know. Generators are definitely mutable objects (they have to save state inside). Unless there's another layer of indirection.

Comment: @user2864740 i’m not sure what you mean, I want the hash to be based off of the *contents* of the generator

Comment: @Kelvin The only way to get the 'content' hash (or perform 'content' equality) for a generator is to *force materialization*.

Comment: @Kelvin technically contents of the generator does not exist (yet). And making it exist destroys (_exhausts_) generator.

Comment: so hash(tuple(i for i in k)) would work, but what if I only care about the values in the tuple, not the tuple container itself? That’s why I asked on the answer below about using sum() to skip the step of having to create a tuple

Comment: @Kelvin what do you want to hash generators *for*? What's the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Kelvin: What do you mean you care only about the values in the tuple?  If you want to hash multiple values together, you have to group them into some kind of container.  In what way do you think making a tuple will interfere with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please ask the question you want answered, not your approach that didn't work. It's perfectly possible to override dictionary lookup to use specific elements of keys only. E.g. `def __getitem__(self, key): dict.__getitem__(self, key[1])` would use only the second element of a key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are two questions here actually:

1. Why do generators have a hash, when e.g. lists do not?
2. Why do you always get the same hash?

For 2, the answer is simple: In this case, hash is based on the object's `id`. Since you don't actually store the object, its memory gets reused. That means the next generator has the same `id` and thus hash.

For 1, the answer is "because they can". `hash` is primarily meant for use in `dict`, `set` and other situations where it allows identifying an object. These situations set the constraint that `a == b` also implies `hash(a) == hash(b)` (the reverse is not constrained).

Now, for `list`, `dict` and other collections, equality is based on content. `[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` regardless whether both are the same objects, for example. This means if something is added to them, their equality changes and thus their `hash` would change as well. Thus, `hash` is undefined, as it must be a constant for it to work in `dict` etc.

In contrast, a generator can have any content. Consider for example a generator providing random values. Thus, it makes no sense to compare generators by content. They are only ever compared by identity. So, `a == b` equals `id(a) == id(b)` for generators. In turn, this means basing `hash(a)` on `id(a)` will always satisfy the constraint by equality on `hash`.

Answer (score 3):

The hash value is presumably based on the object identity, not its contents.  You're probab;y seeing that result because you're not storing the generators, so they're garbage collected and their ids are re-used.  Here are some other examples that show it's not just a single hash all the time:

```
>>> x = (i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> y = (i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> hash(x)
-9223372036852064692
>>> hash(y)
-9223372036852064683
>>> id(x)
43377864
>>> x = (i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> id(x)
43378296
>>> hash(x)
-9223372036852064665
```

As for why Python lets you hash them, it's the same reason it lets you hash all sorts of objects: so you can tell different objects apart and use them as dictionary keys.  It's not meant to tell you about what the generator *does*, just what object it is.  It's no different than this:

```
>>> hash(object())
225805
>>> hash(object())
225805
>>> x = object()
>>> y = object()
>>> hash(x)
225805
>>> hash(y)
225806
```

The idea that if an object is hashable then it is immutable is something of a misconception.  Objects can define any sort of hashing they want as long as it is compatible with their own equality definition.  Instances of user-defined classes, for instance, are hashable in a manner similar to these generator functions (hash based on object id).

People sometimes seem to think that the rule is "if an object is mutable, it is not hashable", but that's not correct.  The actual rule is more like "if an object is not hashable, then it is mutable".  (More specifically, it defines a notion of equality that depends on mutable state, or it explicitly bars hashing for some perverse reason of its own.)  In other words, it doesn't usually make sense to ask why a certain hashable type is hashable; it only makes sense to ask why an unhashable type is unhashable.  The *built-in* mutable types list, dict, and set have a specific reason for being unhashable: they are meant to be compared based on their (mutable) values, not object id.  But just because some other type has some internal state doesn't mean it can't be hashable.  You can define objects that are mutable and hashable all day long.  They just have to define equality and hashability in compatible ways.  Generators indeed cannot be compared for equality based on their contents either:

```
>>> x = (i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> y = (i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> x == y
False
```

For generators, hashing based on values would be uniquely nonsensical, because the values don't exist until they're actually yielded from the generator.  If hashing were based on values, there would be no way to hash a generator that, for instance, used random numbers to decide what to yield next.

Comment: Python doesn't allow list hashing. Your explanation is not good.

Comment: That does not answer a question. There is a reason why Python disallow to compute hash of list or dict. It does not makes any sense (even if it could simply return object id). And it's interesting to know, why such limitation wasn't implemented for generators (it indeed generators are "mutable" by language design - I'm not sure about that, and that's why I upvoted this question).

Comment: oh. That makes sense. What I wanted to do was to hash the values of an integer attribute of objects in a list of objects & I wanted to avoid having to make a tuple. Right now I am using sum(item.i for item in items) instead, is that good if item.i is derived from a random number generator?

Comment: @Kelvin: What do you intend to do with that hash?  Why did you want to avoid making a tuple?  That sounds like a separate issue that might be better addressed in a separate question.

Comment: @Rogalski: See my edits.  There is indeed a reason Python disallows hashing of lists and dicts, but that reason is not that they are mutable.  It is that they can be compared based on mutable state.  Since generator objects can't be, there's no reason for them to be unhashable.  (As for why they're not comparable, it's probably because it's too difficult to determine if two arbitrary generators "do the same thing", and so not worth even trying.)

Comment: storing stuff in a dictionary cache. But one cache entry is valid for more than one kind of query, so computing this hash saves unneeded cache misses, since the only thing that matters is the list of integer attributes that comes with the query. It’s hard to explain. Avoiding a tuple is just an optimization.

Comment: @Kelvin: Avoiding a tuple when what you need is a tuple is not a great optimization.  Again, though, I think what you're getting at here is a separate question that you should ask as such.

Answer (score 0):

Python `object` allows hash and equality: `hash(object())`.

The 'unhashtable type' is a *purposeful restriction* on core *mutable collections* (ie. `list`) *with a defined content-equality comparison* because this avoids some common programming errors. Most notably, when used as dictionary keys.

However, the *content-equality compare for a generator object is the same as the identity compare*: `gen == gen` *implies* `gen is gen`. This is no different than using `hash/==` with the result of `object()`: it often isn't useful, and if it is, identity-hash/equality are expected.

The result of either the hash or the equality of a generator is *independent* upon the future materialized content. Because of this it has no content-useful `==` and thus needs not implement a content-useful `hash`. If it should be a 'unhashtable type' then becomes a gray-area at best because it is no more (or rather, is as) useful than `object()` as a dictionary key.

Thus it is permissible for any value to be returned for the hash of a generator (even if it is duplicated among different generator instances as long as it meets the constraint `hash(x) == hash(x)` -> `x == x`), as long as it is consistent for the given generator instance (as `gen == gen` -> `gen is gen`).

As an implementation detail, I would expect the  hash of a generator to use either the same (as in, not overloaded) or similar implementation to that of a base object.

Answer (score 0):

> **generator expression**
>
> An expression that returns an iterator

If iterators are *hashable*, generator expressions should not be an exception. Iterators are *stateful*, not sure about *mutable*. Or would *stateful* mean *mutable*? More so, iterators are simply object/value factories and nothing more:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> l[:] = [4, 5]
>>> next(it)
4
```

The iterator is not bound to the initial values of the list `l`. So your generator expressions are not hashed relative to the values in `range(2)` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Hashing to the same value is apparently interpreter dependent, and is likely so since you don't have any reference to the generator expressions. I have different results for each:

```
>>> hash(i for i in range(2))
-2143682330
>>> hash(i for i in range(2))
-2143687189
>>> hash(i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
-2143679383
```

If you named the generator expressions, you would probably get different values:

```
>>> ge1 = (i for i in range(2))
>>> ge2 = (i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> hash(ge1)
3801919
>>> hash(ge2)
-2143681547
```